# spring jdbc does not convert java.sql.Date to java.time.LocalDate

Tags: spring-jdbc

The entity has one field, which type is LocalDate. 
I am using Spring jdbcTemplate to query database and using BeanPropertyRowMapper to map the resultSet to the java object. 
But spring does not convert java.sql.Date to java.time.LocalDate.

Here is the error message

org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.sql.Date' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate' for property 'startDate'; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.sql.Date] to required type [java.time.LocalDate] for property 'startDate': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Comment: Which version of Spring? [4.1](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11600) should support it.

Comment: Right so use a Date, Calendar, or TimeStamp object instead.  Those are what are supported, and for good reaason.   Or create a custom property editor.

Comment: what is that good reason?